# How can I do the equivalent of a COUNT/GROUP BY in Excel?

Tags: excel, count, group-by, pivot-table

I have a table in an Excel spreadsheet. I'd like to get the equivalent of doing something like

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1), COUNT(col2)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1
```

in SQL. I was trying to use Pivot Tables, and I am maybe overthinking this, but I'm not used to working in Excel and couldn't figure it out.

All help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't `COUNT(col1)` always be 1? Would that be useful to you?

Comment: I might be asking this wrong or thinking of the SQL wrong as well... Say a value can appear multiple times in column 1. I'm interested in how many times each unique value appears, and I'm also interested in how many unique values appear next to it in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

Well in a Cell Formula it would be (ie)

```
    //Cell Formula
    =Count(A1:A50) // Range
    =Count(A1, A3, A5) // Specific Cells


   // in VBA

   =Sheet1.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

  // Where "A" is the column and 'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)' returns non-blank cells
```

// if you need to check for a specific value in vba:

```
  Dim counter As Integer
 counter = 0

 For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A1:A100").Cells

      If c.Value = "Something" Then
        counter = counter + 1
      End If


 Next

 // Then get your value of the counter variable
```

You might have to do a nested loop to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Open Access instance in background. Put the data. Query by SQL.